# How to copy every file with extension X while keeping the original folder structure? (Unix-like systems)

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to copy every HTML file from an src folder to a dist folder. However, I should like to preserve the original folder structure and if the dist folder does not exist I should like to create a new one.

**Create the folder if it does not exist:**

```
[ -d _dist/ ] || mkdir _dist/
```

**Copy every file:**

```
cp -R _src/**/*.html _dist/
```

**Together:**

```
[ -d _dist/ ] || mkdir _dist/ && cp -R _src/**/*.html _dist/
```

However, if I use ** only the files inside a folder will get copied and if I remove the ** only the root files will get copied. Is this even accomplishable?

Answer (score 3):

```
find _src -type f -name "*.html" -exec cp -t _dist --parents {}  ";"
```

- cp -t : target directory
- --parents : append parents dir to target

This will omit empty (no html-files) dirs. But if you need them, repeat without -name "*.html" but with -type d.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you don't have a version of bash with the `--parents` option, [`cpio`](https://www.gnu.org/software/cpio/manual/) is awesome.

```
[ -d _dist/ ] || cd _src && find . -name '*.html' | cpio -pdm _dist && mv _dist ..
```

This would recursively copy all `html` files into `_dist` while maintaining the directory structures.

↳ [GNU cpio manual - GNU Project](https://www.gnu.org/software/cpio/manual/)